# Formula to find presence of certain keywords in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find certain keywords such as `blogger` or `writing` or `writes` or `.com` in each cell belonging to a column (it's a bio). Specifically a formula to pick up any words that would indicate that the cell being referenced is a person who has a blog.

I was thinking of nesting IF and OR statements, but haven't been able to find anything yet.

Total Excel noob here. Would appreciate any help you guys can provide!

Here's an example of the data I'm dealing with:

[image: SO19687510 question example]

Comment: I see what you want, but what is your question?

Comment: Can you screenshot or type out what columns and a bit of data you have and if possible what kind of output you'd want?

Answer (score 1):

A1 would be the search cell, and in this cell TRUE would be present if A1 contained the "SEARCH TEXT" and it would display "FALSE" otherwise.

```
=if(FIND("SEARCH TEXT",A1),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Source: http://forums.tutorialized.com/ms-excel-97/in-excel-how-to-search-a-text-string-get-true-5215.html

Comment: Thanks Trey! This is really helpful - would there be a way to nest OR statements into this?

Comment: This doesn't work and gives an error if the value doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

With your list of keywords in ColumnD starting in D1, then in Row1:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"="&"*"&D1&"*")
```

copied down to suit should give you the number of instances of each keyword found in ColumnA. Summing the results may be a good guide.

Answer (score 1):

The `FIND` function by itself won't work in this instance as it will return #VALUE error if the text isn't there,

You can use the `ISERROR` function to help deal with this problem.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("a",A21)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

If you want to check multiple conditions then you could use the `AND` function as below:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("a",A21)),ISERROR(FIND("b",A21)),ISERROR(FIND("c",A21))),FALSE,TRUE)
```

NB. This is checking Cell `A21` in this instance.

If you want to check an entire column, using `COUNTIF` is a good suggestion, you could also nest these in an `OR` function to check for multiple instances.

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(D:D,"="&"*foo*")>0,COUNTIF(D:D,"="&"*bar*")>0),TRUE,FALSE)
```